# Why get_posts are only showing five posts (retrieved by assigning a category to them?

Tags: get-posts

Here is the link

http://www.brianfunshine.com/voice-work/voice-page/

This is the code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Voice Page (Two Columns)
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Ten
 * @since Twenty Ten 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>


<?php breadcrumb(); ?>

<?php // this is the main loop ?>
<?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="top-column">

    <div class="post">

        <h2 class="post-title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h2>

        <div class="entry">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="post-meta-data">
            <?php wp_link_pages('before=<p>'.__('Pages:','options').'&after=</p>'); ?>
        </div>

    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else: ?>

    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.','options'); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>

</div><!-- .top-column -->

<div class="left-column">

<?php // retrieve a list of posts with category Voice Audio Demos
$args = array('category_name' => 'Voice Page (Left Column)', 'order' => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page'=>-1);
$customposts = get_posts($args);
foreach($customposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

    <div class="post">

        <h2 class="post-title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h2>

        <div class="entry">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>

    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</div><!-- .left-column -->

<div class="right-column">

<?php // retrieve a list of posts with category Voice Audio Demos
$args = array('category_name' => 'Voice Page (Right Column)', 'orderby' => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page'=>-1);
$customposts = get_posts($args);
foreach($customposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

    <div class="post">

        <h2 class="post-title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h2>

        <div class="entry">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>

    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</div><!-- .left-column -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

It just retrieves posts with category Voice Page (Left Column) and Voice Page (Right Column). I ahve more than 5 posts in that category bu the page is only showing 5:

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you look at the `get_posts` [documentation on Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts), you can see there's a parameter for number of posts you want to display:

> $numberposts
>       (integer) (optional) Number of posts to return. Set to 0 to use the max number of posts per page. Set to
>   -1 to remove the limit.
>
> Default: 5

That's why it's displaying just 5 posts. You need to add the parameter to your args array:

```
$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'Voice Page (Right Column)', 
    'orderby' => 'DESC', 
    'posts_per_page'=>-1, 
    'numberposts'=>-1
);
```

Comment: Also from the Codex, `Note: 'numberposts' and 'posts_per_page' can be used interchangeably.`