# Authors List page : how to exclude posts from certain category

Tags: query-posts

I have a magazine wordpress site in which I have designed a separate page to show all the authors with their nice_names (with URI) and no. of posts.
the code is like this:

```
$current = (intval(get_query_var('paged'))) ? intval(get_query_var('paged')) : 1;

$rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, display_name from $wpdb->users 
WHERE ID NOT IN (1)
ORDER BY display_name");
$author_ids = $wpdb->get_results($query);
global $wp_rewrite;

for ($i=$start;$i < $end ;++$i ) {
   $row = $rows[$i];
 $curauth = get_userdata($row->ID);
 $user_link = get_author_posts_url($curauth->ID);
 $post_count = get_usernumposts($curauth->ID);
?>
```

To show the number of posts each author has, I want to show like this:

- showing number of all posts but excluding a certain category (ID=60)
- showing number of posts in a single category (ID=60)

How do I have to modify the above code?

Comment: What is $row->ID, it's the user's ID right?

Comment: `$row->ID` means user's ID ofcourse.

Comment: If $row->ID is the user ID, then why are you getting the entire userdata array, just for getting the ID again? Use it directly!

Answer (score 1):

Ahh friend, you don't need such a hard way! This should do...

```
<?php
    $curauth = get_userdata($row->ID);
    $user_link = get_author_posts_url($curauth->ID);
    $posts = get_posts(array(
                             'author' => $curauth->ID,
                             'cat' => 60, //for single category, 60
                             'cat' => -60, //for excluding this category
                             'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            )
                      );
    $post_count = count($posts);
?>
```

Remove the commented line as per your requirement. Try and let me know!

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW on line 85

Comment: line-85 contains this : `'cat' => -60,`

Comment: Did you remove the comments? And one of those lines?

Comment: I have cleared this error by modifying the line as `'author' => $curauth->ID,` ... but the problem is , the result (after deducting cat=60 posts) is showing for some authors as "5" only where as they have more than 5-posts.

Comment: That is what 'posts_per_page' is for... The default number returned is 5, but if you set 'posts_per_page' as -1, it will return all posts. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters

Comment: Better, post your code here... I'll see it.

Comment: Hi Rutwick, here is the complete code of my Authors List Template : http://pastebin.com/81jpa69z

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1512/discussion-between-rutwick-gangurde-and-syed)

Comment: Remove the comma ( , ) after 'posts_per_page' => -1 on line no. 85.

Comment: Hi Rutwick, I am online now. I have already removed that comma as I know that it is the last item of array hence should be removed. But no way. All the authors which have more than 5-posts have been showing as only 5-posts.

Comment: Whoa...! Now that is one tricky thing. This is the final thing I could ask you to do... Like shown in this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7830/why-get-posts-are-only-showing-five-posts-retrieved-by-assigning-a-category-to-t, use **'numberposts' => -1** or try removing it completely. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Rutwick. zabardast! Great point. yeah it works. & ofcourse, this code should be added `numberposts' => -1` . Thanks a lot buddy.